# HTML/CSS - Page scrolls (y) for no obvious reason

Tags: html, css, scroll

Simple question this time - why does this page have scroll-bars? I can think of no reason - checked all the elements with firebug, none is even reaching the bottom of the page.

Here is the CSSdesk: http://cssdesk.com/hcAPj
Thanks

Comment: A problem with your mouse maybe?

Comment: Well I would like it to stop scrolling if possible. If not I would like to at least know why it does it.

Comment: Page does not scroll down upon load for me.

Comment: Oh maybe I didn't express myself correctly - it doesn't scroll down by itself, but it is able to scroll down. Why is that happening?

Comment: I know I did put a overflow: scroll in the body, but that is to avoid page reposition when I switch to page with larger content. And indeed the scroll bar is present on the right of every page, but it is only scollable on the Gallery page I linked.

Answer (score 1):

You defined the `#sidebar` element as having `min-height:100%`, but there is no reference (element with explicit height set) other than the document. Therefore, `100%` of the window (frame) height is used, and since it's not flush with the top it overflows off the bottom.

Comment: Did anyone even try this? It doesn't work, removing the min-height.

Comment: I didn't really understand what you mean but the problem was a 'position: relative' that I forgot to remove from the content div css. Now it is all fine.